# webGL, javascript: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 1

Tags: javascript, graphics, webgl, shading

I'm not understanding how to fix this error.  I was able to do an xz-plane with two spheres in two corners.  The spheres are shaded (one goroud, one phong) with the plane being a flat color.  However, when I tried to texturize the plane in a checkerboard pattern, I started to receive this error.

Here is my HTML:

```
<html>
<script id="BsphereV" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
attribute vec4 vPosition;
attribute vec4 vNormal;
varying vec3 N;
varying vec3 L;
varying vec3 E;
uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform vec4 lightPosition;
uniform mat3 normalMatrix;

void main() {
    //----- Color Code
    // vPos in eye coords
    vec3 pos = (modelViewMatrix * vPosition).xyz;

    // directional light check
    if(lightPosition.w == 0.0) L = normalize(lightPosition.xyz);
    else L = normalize(lightPosition.xyz - pos);

    // vPos to eye vector
    E = -normalize(pos);

    // transform vNorm to eye coords
    N = normalize(normalMatrix * vNormal.xyz);

    //----- Postion code
    mat4 SnT = mat4(0.3, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                    0.0, 0.3, 0.0, 0.0,
                    0.0, 0.0, 0.3, 0.0,
                    0.7, 0.0,-0.7, 1.0);

    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * SnT * vPosition;
}
</script>

<script id="SphereCB" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
precision mediump float;
varying vec3 N;
varying vec3 L;
varying vec3 E;
uniform vec4 ambientProduct;
uniform vec4 diffuseProduct;
uniform vec4 specularProduct;
uniform float shininess;

void main() {
    vec4 fColor;

    // halfway vector
    vec3 H = normalize(L + E);

    // Light calcs
    vec4 ambient = ambientProduct;

    float Kd = max(dot(L, N), 0.0);
    vec4 diffuse = Kd * diffuseProduct;

    float Ks = pow(max(dot(N, H), 0.0), shininess);
    vec4 specular = Ks * specularProduct;

    if(dot(L, N) < 0.0) specular = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    // set color
    //fColor = ambient + diffuse + specular;
    fColor = ambient + specular;
    fColor.a = 1.0;

    gl_FragColor = fColor;
}
</script>

<script id="RsphereV" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
attribute vec4 vPosition;
attribute vec4 vNormal;
varying vec4 fColor;
uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform vec4 ambientProduct;
uniform vec4 diffuseProduct;
uniform vec4 specularProduct;
uniform vec4 lightPosition;
uniform float shininess;
uniform mat3 normalMatrix;

void main() {
    //----- Color code
    // vPos in eye coords
    vec3 pos = (modelViewMatrix * vPosition).xyz;

    // vec from vPos to light source
    vec3 L;

    // directional light check
    if(lightPosition.w == 0.0) L = normalize(lightPosition.xyz);
    else L = normalize(lightPosition.xyz - pos);

    // vPos to eye vector
    vec3 E = -normalize(pos);

    // halfway vector
    vec3 H = normalize(L + E);

    // transform vNorm to eye coords
    vec3 N = normalize(normalMatrix * vNormal.xyz);

    // Light calcs
    vec4 ambient = ambientProduct;

    float Kd = max(dot(L, N), 0.0);
    vec4 diffuse = Kd * diffuseProduct;

    float Ks = pow(max(dot(N, H), 0.0), shininess);
    vec4 specular = Ks * specularProduct;

    if(dot(L, N) < 0.0) specular = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    // set color
    //fColor = ambient + diffuse + specular;
    fColor = ambient + diffuse;
    fColor.a = 1.0;

    //----- Position code    
    mat4 SnT = mat4(0.3, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                    0.0, 0.3, 0.0, 0.0,
                    0.0, 0.0, 0.3, 0.0,
                   -0.7, 0.0,-0.7, 1.0);

    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * SnT * vPosition;
}
</script>

<script id="SphereCR" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
precision mediump float;
varying vec4 fColor;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = fColor;
}
</script>

<script id="floorV" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
attribute vec4 vPosition;
attribute vec2 vTexCoord;
varying vec2 fTexCoord;
uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;

void main() {
    mat4 SnT = mat4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                    0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                    0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
                    0.0, 0.7, 0.0, 1.0);

    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * SnT * vPosition;
    fTexCoord = vTexCoord;
}
</script>

<script id="floorC" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
precision mediump float;
varying vec2 fTexCoord;
uniform sampler2D texture;

void main() {
    vec4 fColor = vec4(0, 1, 0, 1);
    gl_FragColor = fColor * texture2D(texture, fTexCoord);
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../Common/webgl-utils.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Common/initShaders.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Common/MV.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assign4snt.js"></script>

<body>
<canvas id="gl-canvas" width="600" height="600">
Oops... your browser doesn't support the HTML5 canvas element.
</canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my javascript:

```
//----- General variables
var gl;
var canvas;
var pointsArray = [];

//----- Sphere variables
var pSphereB;
var pSphereR;
var index = 0;
var indexRedStart;
var numTimesToSubdivide = 4;
var va = vec4( 0.0,  0.0, -1.0, 1);
var vb = vec4( 0.0,  0.9,  0.3, 1);
var vc = vec4(-0.8, -0.5,  0.3, 1);
var vd = vec4( 0.8, -0.5,  0.3, 1);
var normalsArray = [];

//----- Light variables
var lightPosition = vec4(5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 0.0);
var lightAmbient = vec4(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1.0);
var lightDiffuse = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
var lightSpecular = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
var pointLight = true;

//----- Red Sphere Coloring (goroud)
var redMatAmbient = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
var redMatDiffuse = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
var redMatSpecular = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
var redMatShininess = 150.0;
var normalMatrixR;
var normalMatrixLocR;

//----- Blue Sphere Coloring (phong)
var blueMatAmbient = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
var blueMatDiffuse = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
var blueMatSpecular = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
var blueMatShininess = 8.0;
var normalMatrixB;
var normalMatrixLocB;

//----- Plane variables
var pFloor;
var texCoordsArray = [];
var texSize = 64;
var texture;

//----- Camera variables
var modelViewMatrix;
var projectionMatrix;
var bMVLoc;
var bPVLoc;
var rMVLoc;
var rPVLoc;
var fMVLoc;
var fPVLoc;
var fov = 45;
var near = 0.5;
var far = 1000;
var x;
var y = 3;
var z;
var eye;
var at = vec3(0, 0, 0);
var up = vec3(0, 1, 0);
var degrees = 90;
var angles;
var RADIUS = 3;

//----- Checkerboard Texture
// create using floats
var image1 = new Array();
    for(var i = 0; i < texSize; i++) image1[i] = new Array();
    for(var i = 0; i < texSize; i++)
        for(var j = 0; j < texSize; j++)
            image1[i][j] = new Float32Array(4);
    for(var i = 0; i < texSize; i++)
        for(var j = 0; j < texSize; j++) {
            var c = (((i & 0x8) == 0) ^ ((j & 0x8) == 0));
            image1[i][j] = [c, c, c, 1];
        }
// convert floats to ubytes
var image2 = new Uint8Array(4 * texSize * texSize);
    for(var i = 0; i < texSize; i++)
        for(var j = 0; j < texSize; j++)
            for(var k = 0; k < 4; k++)
                image2[4 * texSize * i + 4 * j + k] = 255 * image1[i][j][k];

//==============================================================================
window.onload = function init() {
    //----- Initialize WebGL
    canvas = document.getElementById("gl-canvas");
    gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL(canvas);
    if (!gl) alert("WebGL isn't available");
    gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    gl.clearColor(0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 1);
    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

    //----- Initialize Shaders
    pSphereB = initShaders(gl, "BsphereV", "SphereCB");
    pSphereR = initShaders(gl, "RsphereV", "SphereCR");
    pFloor = initShaders(gl, "floorV", "floorC");

    //----- Create Spheres
    sphere(va, vb, vc, vd, numTimesToSubdivide);

    indexRedStart = index;
    sphere(va, vb, vc, vd, numTimesToSubdivide);

    //----- Create Plane
    plane();

    //----- Light Calcs (Red Sphere)
    var redAmbientProd = mult(lightAmbient, redMatAmbient);
    var redDiffuseProd = mult(lightDiffuse, redMatDiffuse);
    var redSpecularProd = mult(lightSpecular, redMatSpecular);
    var blueAmbientProd = mult(lightAmbient, blueMatAmbient);
    var blueDiffuseProd = mult(lightDiffuse, blueMatDiffuse);
    var blueSpecularProd = mult(lightSpecular, blueMatSpecular);

    //----- Vertex Buffer Code
    var vBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(pointsArray), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    var vPosBlue = gl.getAttribLocation(pSphereB, "vPosition");
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(vPosBlue, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vPosBlue);

    var vPosRed = gl.getAttribLocation(pSphereR, "vPosition");
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(vPosRed, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vPosRed);

    var vPlane = gl.getAttribLocation(pFloor, "vPosition");
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(vPlane, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vPlane);

    //----- Texture Buffer Code
    var tBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, tBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(texCoordsArray), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    var vTexCoord = gl.getAttribLocation(pFloor, "vTexCoord");
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(vTexCoord, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vTexCoord);

    //----- Normals Buffer Code
    var nBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, nBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(normalsArray), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    var nBlue = gl.getAttribLocation(pSphereB, "vNormal");
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(nBlue, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(nBlue);

    var nRed = gl.getAttribLocation(pSphereR, "vNormal");
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(nRed, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(nRed);

    //----- Process Texture
    configureTexture(image2);

    //----- Link Camera
    bMVLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(pSphereB, "modelViewMatrix");
    bPVLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(pSphereB, "projectionMatrix");
    rMVLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(pSphereR, "modelViewMatrix");
    rPVLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(pSphereR, "projectionMatrix");
    fMVLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(pFloor, "modelViewMatrix");
    fPVLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(pFloor, "projectionMatrix");

    //----- Link Nomrmals
    normalMatrixLocR = gl.getUniformLocation(pSphereR, "normalMatrix");
    normalMatrixLocB = gl.getUniformLocation(pSphereB, "normalMatrix");

    //----- Link Blue Lights
    gl.useProgram(pSphereB);
    gl.uniform4fv(gl.getUniformLocation(pSphereB, "ambientProduct"),
            flatten(blueAmbientProd));
    gl.uniform4fv(gl.getUniformLocation(pSphereB, "diffuseProduct"),
            flatten(blueDiffuseProd));
    gl.uniform4fv(gl.getUniformLocation(pSphereB, "specularProduct"),
            flatten(blueSpecularProd));
    gl.uniform4fv(gl.getUniformLocation(pSphereB, "lightPosition"),
            flatten(lightPosition));
    gl.uniform1f(gl.getUniformLocation(pSphereB, "shininess"),
            blueMatShininess);

    //----- Link Red Lights
    gl.useProgram(pSphereR);
    gl.uniform4fv(gl.getUniformLocation(pSphereR, "ambientProduct"),
            flatten(redAmbientProd));
    gl.uniform4fv(gl.getUniformLocation(pSphereR, "diffuseProduct"),
            flatten(redDiffuseProd));
    gl.uniform4fv(gl.getUniformLocation(pSphereR, "specularProduct"),
            flatten(redSpecularProd));
    gl.uniform4fv(gl.getUniformLocation(pSphereR, "lightPosition"),
            flatten(lightPosition));
    gl.uniform1f(gl.getUniformLocation(pSphereR, "shininess"),
            redMatShininess);

    //----- Initialize camera location    
    setInitialXZ();

    //----- Navigation Control
    window.addEventListener("keydown", function() {
       if(event.keyCode == 65 || event.keyCode == 37) {    // A (left)
           degrees -= 5;
           angles = radians(degrees);
           x = RADIUS * Math.cos(angles);
           z = RADIUS * Math.sin(angles);
       }
       if(event.keyCode == 68 || event.keyCode == 39) {    // D (right)
           degrees += 5;
           angles = radians(degrees);
           x = RADIUS * Math.cos(angles);
           z = RADIUS * Math.sin(angles);
       }
    });

    //----- Draw Screen
    render();
}

//==============================================================================
function render() {
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    //----- Set Camera
    projectionMatrix = perspective(fov, canvas.width/canvas.height, near, far);
    eye = vec3(x, y, z);
    modelViewMatrix = lookAt(eye, at, up);
    normalMatrix = [
        vec3(modelViewMatrix[0][0], modelViewMatrix[0][1],
                modelViewMatrix[0][2]),
        vec3(modelViewMatrix[1][0], modelViewMatrix[1][1],
                modelViewMatrix[1][2]),
        vec3(modelViewMatrix[2][0], modelViewMatrix[2][1],
                modelViewMatrix[2][2]),
    ];

    //----- Draw Blue Sphere
    gl.useProgram(pSphereB);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(bMVLoc, false, flatten(modelViewMatrix));
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(bPVLoc, false, flatten(projectionMatrix));
    gl.uniformMatrix3fv(normalMatrixLocB, false, flatten(normalMatrix));
    for(var i = 0; i < indexRedStart; i += 3)
        gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, i, 3);

    //----- Draw Red Sphere
    gl.useProgram(pSphereR);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(rMVLoc, false, flatten(modelViewMatrix));
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(rPVLoc, false, flatten(projectionMatrix));
    gl.uniformMatrix3fv(normalMatrixLocR, false, flatten(normalMatrix));
    for(var i = indexRedStart; i < index; i += 3)
        gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, i, 3);

    //----- Draw Plane
    gl.useProgram(pFloor);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(fMVLoc, false, flatten(modelViewMatrix));
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(fPVLoc, false, flatten(projectionMatrix));
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, index, 6);

    //----- Draw Again
    requestAnimFrame(render);
}

//==============================================================================
function configureTexture(image) {
    texture = gl.createTexture();
    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, texSize, texSize, 0, gl.RGBA,
            gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
    gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_2D);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
            gl.NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
}

//==============================================================================
function setInitialXZ() {
    angles = radians(degrees);
    x = RADIUS * Math.cos(angles);
    z = RADIUS * Math.sin(angles);
}

//==============================================================================
function plane() {
    var vertices = [
        vec4( 1,-1, 1, 1),  // 0 #4 upper right
        vec4(-1,-1, 1, 1),  // 1 #3 upper left
        vec4(-1,-1,-1, 1),  // 2 #1 lower left
        vec4( 1,-1,-1, 1)   // 3 #2 lower right
    ];

    var texCoord = [
        vec2(0, 0),
        vec2(0, 1),
        vec2(1, 1),
        vec2(1, 0)
    ];

    pointsArray.push(vertices[0]);
    pointsArray.push(vertices[1]);
    pointsArray.push(vertices[2]);
    pointsArray.push(vertices[0]);
    pointsArray.push(vertices[2]);
    pointsArray.push(vertices[3]);

    texCoordsArray.push(texCoord[0]);
    texCoordsArray.push(texCoord[1]);
    texCoordsArray.push(texCoord[2]);
    texCoordsArray.push(texCoord[0]);
    texCoordsArray.push(texCoord[2]);
    texCoordsArray.push(texCoord[3]);
}

//==============================================================================
function sphere(a, b, c, d, n) {
    divideTriangle(a, b, c, n);
    divideTriangle(d, c, b, n);
    divideTriangle(a, d, b, n);
    divideTriangle(a, c, d, n);
}

//==============================================================================
function divideTriangle(a, b, c, count) {
    if (count > 0) {
        //----- Find midpoint
        var ab = mix(a, b, 0.5);
        var ac = mix(a, c, 0.5);
        var bc = mix(b, c, 0.5);

        //----- Find Normal Vector
        ab = normalize(ab, true);
        ac = normalize(ac, true);
        bc = normalize(bc, true);

        //----- Repeat
        divideTriangle(a, ab, ac, count-1);
        divideTriangle(ab, b, bc, count-1);
        divideTriangle(bc, c, ac, count-1);
        divideTriangle(ab, bc, ac, count-1);
    } else {
        triangle(a, b, c);
    }
}

//==============================================================================
function triangle(a, b, c) {
    pointsArray.push(a);
    pointsArray.push(b);
    pointsArray.push(c);

    normalsArray.push(a[0], a[1], a[2], 0);
    normalsArray.push(b[0], b[1], b[2], 0);
    normalsArray.push(c[0], c[1], c[2], 0);

    index += 3;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Attributes are global state. That means you have to set them before each draw call (or each change in vertices), not at init time.

The code seems to think that attributes are per-program.

For example this part

```
var vPosBlue = gl.getAttribLocation(pSphereB, "vPosition");
gl.vertexAttribPointer(vPosBlue, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vPosBlue);

var vPosRed = gl.getAttribLocation(pSphereR, "vPosition");
gl.vertexAttribPointer(vPosRed, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vPosRed);

var vPlane = gl.getAttribLocation(pFloor, "vPosition");
gl.vertexAttribPointer(vPlane, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vPlane);
```

The code above is probably setting the same attribute 3 times meaning only the last one is having any effect since if they are the same attribute location the global attribute at that location has been overwritten with the last 2 lines.

uniforms are shader program state. **ALL OTHER STATE IS GLOBAL**. For example attributes, texture units, and everything else.

[You might find this article useful](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-drawing-multiple-things.html)